# When having two wrapper class arrays of similar value in lightning component, updating one of them will automatically update another

Tags: lightning-aura-components

So when we have two arrays of Apex wrapper class records in lightning component of the same source (one is a slice(0) of another), Updating one of them will result in another one updated accordingly. It seems to me that they are pointing to one temp object. But I am not sure how this is happening. It is really strange to me.

I made the below proof of concept code. I have made it as small as I could:

**Component:**

```
<aura:component controller="LanceTestController">
    <aura:attribute name="testList" type="SampleWrapper[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="dupList" type="SampleWrapper[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.testList}" var="it">
        <ui:inputText label="Text" value="{!it.num}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
    <footer class="slds-size_1-of-1">                
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save Changes" onclick="{!c.saveChanges}" />
    </footer>
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller:**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getSamples");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.testList", result);
            component.set("v.dupList", result.slice(0));
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    saveChanges : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("test list is: " + component.get("v.testList")[2].num);
        console.log("dup list is: " + component.get("v.dupList")[2].num);
    }
})
```

**Wrapper Class:**

```
public class SampleWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled public Integer num;
    public SampleWrapper(Integer n) {
        num = n;
    }
}
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
public class LanceTestController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<SampleWrapper> getSamples() {
        List<SampleWrapper> sampWrapperLst = new List<SampleWrapper>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            sampWrapperLst.add(new SampleWrapper(i));
        }
        return sampWrapperLst;
    }
}
```

So when you edit anything on the page, both testList and dupList changes at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is standard JavaScript behavior. [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) makes a "[shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy)", which means that only the values of an array are copied. If the value in the array happens to be an Object, the memory address/reference is copied, not the object itself. For a single layer wrapper, you'd do this:

```
component.set("v.dupList", result.map(v=>Object.assign({},v)));
```

This will create shallow copies of the object. If you need more than one layer of duplication, though, you might need a more complicated solution, such as recursion, or JSON:

```
component.set("v.dupList", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
```