# I am getting error when ever i am trying to update a object in an object array in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

When ever i am trying to update a value in the object array i am greeting script error, even splice does not works below are two snippets in lwc js.

```
   let allValues=this.budgetData;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('allValues ' +  JSON.stringify(allValues) );
   for(let i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++){
       if(allValues[i].Id === event.target.name ){
           // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('allValues ' +  JSON.stringify(allValues[i]) );
        allValues.splice(i,1);
       }
   }


   let allValues=this.budgetData;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('allValues ' +  JSON.stringify(allValues) );
   for(let i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++){
       if(allValues[i].Id === event.target.name ){
           // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('allValues ' +  JSON.stringify(allValues[i]) );
        allValues[i]= objectvalue;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to go through [how to ask questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). With the current form of your question, it is not clear what issue you are facing, on which line, etc. Also with the current code snippet, it just seems it is not related to LWC in particular but possibly a JS issue. Please [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/286493/edit) to provide more details on the issue you are facing for someone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Jayant](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/54851/jayant-dassays) says, hard to know without more context, but best guess is that you need to assign the response to new array using Object.assign - see [here](http://Best%20guess%20is%20that%20it%20is%20similar%20to%20this%20issue%20(https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246899/when-having-two-wrapper-class-arrays-of-similar-value-in-lightning-component-up/246900#246900)%20-%20basicallt%20yuou) for example. Basically, any data you get back from Apex is read only so you don't invalidate the cache - so to manipulate it, you need to make a new copy